# Problem with my setListAdapter()

Tags: android

I don't know what's going on I first posted this in a class that extends Activity. But even after changing it to a ListActivity it still doesn't work. I'll dumb it down to where I think the problem is.

```
public class PassScreen extends ListActivity {
String[] items = {"lorem","ipsum", "dolor"};// I have it calling an xml file but switched it to this just to see if that was the problem.
setContentView(R.layout.passwordscreen);
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            items));
```

I don't get what's wrong. This is what my book uses. I checked to make sure the xml file displays the proper ListView and it does. But here it is anyway:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/selection"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<ListView
  android:id="@android:id/list"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so I just found out the problem. ARGH!! This is why I love programing. My Layout needed an orientation.

So:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

Should have looked like this:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" // This is the difference. 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
 getListView().setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
        getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

Comment: That worked. I just have no idea how to use anything without an xml file.

Comment: "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1" this line indicate LISTVIEW.. and you have listactivity then listview automatic generate by this code

Comment: I don't fully understand. Say I want to change a Text view to what was selected. Like this. How would I go about doing it?                                                                          public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id){
//     selection.setText(items.get(position).toString());
     selection.setText(items[position]);